# Como creo un Select en laravel que llene segun opcion seleccionada?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

**Esta en mi vista con el selectview**

```
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="dni">Chofer</label>
            <select name="dni" class="form-control selectpicker" id="dni" 
              data-live-search="true">  
                <option value="">--Seleccione el *DNI--</option>
                 @foreach($chofers as $chofer)
                    <option value="{{$chofer['cuitdni']}}">{{$chofer['cuitdni']}}
                 @endforeach
              </select>
         </div>
     </div>
```

**Luego de que se ejecute el select quiero llenar el campo nombre del DNI seleccionado (el que va en el select que es numero de cliente), cómo haría?, gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar**

Comment: ¿Todo esto con o sin AJAX?, por que en función de eso la respuesta variará, por otro lado ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: yo lo hice con un scripts asi en value:  <option value="{{$chofer->id}}_{{$chofer-dnil}}_{{$chofer->nombre}}">{{$chofer->chofer}}</option>, despues lo separe con una funcion y me los llena excelente el temaes que despues no se como mandar el id solo al metodo store porque esos campos son solo para que el usuario los vea, solo guardaría el id

Comment: A qué te refieres con "llenar el campo nombre del DNI seleccionado"? Llenarlo dónde?

Comment: Luego de seleccionar el cliente por Numero quiero llenar el nombre de este en un campo que tengo abajo

Comment: Cuando se seleccione un cliente por numero, en la variable `name="dni"`, se cambiara por el `dni del cliente`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un AJAX que se ejecute cuando detecte el cambio del `select`:

```js
$('#presentation').on('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/product-prices/' + value,
            success: function success(data) {
                $('element').text(data); // Si es un elemento como una <p>
                $('element').value(data); // Si es algo como un input(type="text")
            },
            error: function error(data) {
                console.log("Error", data);
            }
        });
});
```

Y en tu método del controlador, regreses la info que necesitas.

O si, literalmente, solo necesitas el texto que aparece en la opción seleccionada. Puedes hacer lo siguiente, sin AJAX:

```js
$('#presentation').on('change', function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('element').text(text); // Esto para un elemento tal como un <p>
    $('element').val(text); // Esto en caso de que algo como input(type="text")
});
```